# linux use board init file and device tree simultaneously

Tags: linux, device-tree

Is it possible to simultaneously use "board init file"   and "device tree" for peripheral device configuration in linux kernel? For example I have a set of peripherals. Half of them are fixed and other harf are changeable. Can I keep the fixed peripherals in a "board init file" and the rest in "device tree"?

Comment: pls go through this http://elinux.org/images/5/5c/ELCE2013_-_DT_War.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kiran If you check the code, still they haven't removed the board file. So you can safely say that both could be used in parallel. But it is not advisable to keep half of the peripheral in device tree and other half in board file. As it goes against the reason why device tree was brought in the first place.